# Subdomain constraint if it isn't www

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If the subdomain is not 'www', I want to route requests to a special controller.

```
www.example.com    // home#index
section1.example.com // section#index
section1.example.com/name123  // section#name 
section9.example.com // section#index

routes.rb

root 'home#index'
```

How can I force requests to use the section controller with the above criteria?

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: Section do                 #-> only subdomain routes (non WWW)
   resources :section, path: "", only: :show  #-> http://sectionx.url.com/:id
end
root "home#index" #-> should be last so that above routes are parsed first


#lib/section.rb
module Section

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Section.exists?(request.subdomain) if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
    end

end
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Comment: I'm getting an error saying there are 2 root's defined. `Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Just remove the scoped root

Comment: but then section#index isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: Yep, if it's `path: ""`, it will have `sectionx.url.com/` as the default route

Comment: I was kind of busy then, sorry for the terse replies. I would have expected "root" to work, but evidently not. As such, since we're scoping around a particular resource, accessing that resource with no path definition should do as we need